# Windows Phone 7 and System.Xml.Linq library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, reference

I'm trying to follow this tutorial about WP7 development:  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/introduction-to-windows-mobile-7-development/

It's talking about using XElements, which require the `System.Xml.Linq` library, but I can't find a way to add it to the project references. When I go to add reference, the .NET list is empty, and it's saying it's filtered to Windows Phone 7.

The tutorial might be out of date. Is the library even available for WP7? Is there a different way to read XML on the platform?

How can I get it working?

EDIT:

The same problem is described here:
http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/1127-add-reference-net-tab-empty/

The suggested fix doesn't work for me.

EDIT:

Apparently this is a bug in the Silverlight 4 Tools:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/529718/empty-net-tab-when-adding-a-reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assembly list should not be empty when adding a reference from the .NET tab even for a Windows Phone 7 project, so it sounds like you might have an issue with Visual Studio.

However, you could try using the Browse tab instead. On my system (64-bit), the assembly is in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone folder.

Answer (score 9):

That is the correct *Assembly* you need to work with *XML* in `Windows Phone 7`. Not sure why it does not show up in your `Add Reference` dialog.

It should be like following:

[image: Add Reference WP7]

What version of WP7 developer tools are you using?

Comment: Yeah, that list is completely empty for me. Will try to fix my VS. I'm using the latest version of the developer tools, but I already had VS 2010 installed.

Comment: Thanx for saving my valuable time :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, LINQ to XML is *definitely* available for Windows Phone 7. If you aren't seeing *any* available references to add, that sounds like your development environment is a little bit messed up...