# Parsing XML from Windows Phone 7

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

```
<ResponseOfArrayOfQuestions>
  <Result>
    <Questions>
        <DESCRIPTION>Ask me?</DESCRIPTION>
        <DIFFICULTY>1</DIFFICULTY>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <LK_recordstatusid>True</LK_recordstatusid>
        <oAnswers>
            <Answers>
                <DESCRIPTION>me</DESCRIPTION>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <ISCORRECT>False</ISCORRECT>
            </Answers>
            <Answers>
                <DESCRIPTION>you</DESCRIPTION>
                <ID>2</ID>
                <ISCORRECT>False</ISCORRECT>
            </Answers>
            <Answers>
                <DESCRIPTION>Everyone</DESCRIPTION>
                <ID>3</ID>
                <ISCORRECT>False</ISCORRECT>
            </Answers>
            <Answers>
                <DESCRIPTION>NoOne</DESCRIPTION>
                <ID>4</ID>
                <ISCORRECT>True</ISCORRECT>
            </Answers>
        </oAnswers>
    </Questions>
    <Questions>
    </Questions>
    .
    .
    .
  </Result>
  <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
  <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
</ResponseOfArrayOfQuestions>
```

---

Can anyone please help me parse this so so confusing XML which I have been trying for over days? :(  Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract from this XML? Are you creating classes to represent each answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594).

Here are links to Stackoverflow Q&A of its usage:

[Windows Phone 7 and System.Xml.Linq library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119312/windows-phone-7-and-system-xml-linq/5122271#5122271)

[LINQ to read XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml-c)

Comment: Yup, I have gone through all of them. The problem is I am getting null. I am not sure which part I should use as Elements and which part I should use as Descendants.. :S

Comment: Ok, then please edit your question add the exact error details in it.